# Finding a specific model with some condition associated with another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've checked like every other question here and can't seem to find the answer. 
I have

Path:

1. `attr_accessible :location, :total_time, :visits`
2. `belongs_to :trackedsite, :touch => true`

Trackedsite:

1. `attr_accessible :total_time, :url, :visits`
2. `has_many :paths, :autosave => true`

I want to find a Path belonging to a Trackedsite with a specific location

I have tried:

```
@trackedsite = Trackedsite.find_by_url(params[:url_string])
@path = @trackedsite.find_by_location(params[:path_string])
```

But I get "no such column: paths.trackedsite_id" (which is correct, that column doesn't exist, should I be adding something to my migration?)

Comment: "Both give me errors..." What errors?

Comment: "No such column path.location"

Comment: Do both queries give you the same error? Have you run rake db:migrate recently?

Comment: I changed what my second query is because the one I had before was wrong to begin with. I did run the migration. The error I get now is "no such column: paths.trackedsite_id"

It ran `SELECT "paths".* FROM "paths" WHERE "paths".trackedsite_id" IS NULL AND "paths"."location" = 'location' LIMIT 1`

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: I added an image if it helps. Line 55 that it is referring to is `@path = @trackedsite.paths.find_by_location(params[:path_string])`

Comment: Is there a location column in the DB? As @varatis asked did your migration succeed?

Comment: I did run the migration and am staring at my migration file and it does indeed have `t.string :location`

Comment: I only associated the two files in code (`using the belongs_to` and `has_many relationship`). I didn't add anything to my migration so it makes sense that the database has no idea that they are related - yet is looking for trackedsite_id in path? `@paths = @trackedsite.paths` seems to work but how do I further filter thesem results? I tried splitting this up into two parts (`@paths = @trackedsite.paths` and `@path = @paths.find_by_location(params[:location])` but I get the same error.

Comment: When you look at the *database* is the column in there? Well, you edited; that's different then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associations work by having foreign keys. If your path `belongs_to` a `TrackedSite` by convention there needs to be a `trackedsite_id`, otherwise there's no link between the entities.

Comment: How can I update it? I tried adding `t.integer :trackedsite_id` to my migration and then running `rake db:reset` but it still says the column doesn't exist. I tried `rake db:drop` but it failed saying it couldnt find the sqlite db. I am on rails 3.2.12

Comment: @Coolguy123 You run a *new* migration. It's not going to run an *old* migration that's already been run unless you roll back.

Comment: Okay thanks. For anyone wondering what I did:
I ran `rake db:rollback` to undo the migration, edited the migration, then ran `rake db:migrate`